# Do you think [meta information] affects users' decision when vote on SO?

Tags: discussion, voting, tactical-downvoting, psychology

I was thinking of this... when I vote on SO, i will focus not only on the answers... I find myself doing almost subconscious evaluations of people, reputation and vote count while deciding.

For example:

Sometimes...

- I will vote based on reputation

  - I will give the low rep guy a vote as long as the answer is good.
  - I will give the high rep guy a vote if it's something I don't know a great deal about ( the trust factor)
  - I downvote a high rep poster if it doesn't answer the question strictly ( I'm more picky with the higher rep posters, as they tend to get automatic votes anyhow )
- I will vote based on vote count

  - If the top two are with a vote or two... but are both good answers, I will vote for the lower vote, to promote **competition**
  - I will often vote on any answer at 9 points, just to throw it over 10
  - I will vote up a -1 answer/question, to make it 0 if it has any redeeming quality
- I will vote based on controversy

  - I will vote up controversial answers, if they're well-thought out.
  - I will vote down accepted answers if another answer is better ( *if it wasn't accepted, I'd just leave it be* )

**What about you?**

**edit**
Please re-read the above in the 3rd person

Comment: *I will vote up a -1 answer/question, to make it 0 if it has any redeeming quality* **Burn** in hell!

Comment: *I downvote a high rep poster if it doesn't answer the question strictly* Sometimes the *questions asked by those low rep users* are the reason you can't answer the question well. Half the time it turns into a tech support call. "Why won't my script work?!?!"

Comment: OOohhh... I sense anger. Don't be hatin' on the question, folks. And, yes... I hold high rep posters to a higher standard, subconsciously, don't you?

Comment: @json: Why not? I mean, if the answer has merit I find myself balancing it out. SO is a community effort and sometimes downvotes aren't necessarily justified.

Comment: -1 for admitted pity upvoting. Flagged. Voted to close. Called parents of OP, suggested counselling. Alerted police. Extra-terrestrial overlord beacon deployed, message reads: "ATOMITON IS A META VOTER STOP SUGGEST RAISING POWER LEVEL OF BRAIN CONTROL NODE STOP DATA READOUT FROM RECTAL PROBING ANOMALOUS STOP".

Comment: Votes aren't "justified". They're opinions in the first place, representative of the individual who cast it. The only time I'd vote a -1 question up is if I would've voted the question up at any other vote count: because I felt it should be upvoted. Be it for a clear question, a question that should be answered, or I agree with it. Same for answers.

Comment: @Atomiton: what @ccomet said. *sometimes downvotes aren't necessarily justified* nor are some upvotes.

Comment: Ppl. I'm not talking about something that you regularly do here. There is definitely a psychological aspect to SO. Answers aren't solely based on their merit.

Comment: @Atomiton: They are to *good* users.

Comment: The question one needs to ask is... if Jon Skeet had opened this question... what would the response be?

Comment: @Atom: it would be generally accepted as sarcasm from Jon Skeet and tagged with `Always Friday...`

Comment: Assuming that he used his normal prose but otherwise had the same content and goal as your inquiry (as in he was serious, not sarcastic)... I would vote the same way. I might be a lot more disappointed considering all the stories, but I wouldn't let that specifically affect my vote. Even taking into account subconscious choicemaking.

Comment: @ccomet. See, I think you're in a minority. Like it or not, I still think there is an amount of subconscious voting. I still don't feel that this question isn't useful. If nothing else, it's worth probing. I know this question will likely be closed, but I really don't think it deserves the gratuitous downvoting. You'd be surprised about how much we base our "opinions" on things other than merit, as much as we try not to.

Comment: I don't disagree with basing an opinion on something aside from merit. I do disagree with expressing my opinion without actually consulting my opinion. Which is (for me, as it were) what I would be doing if I voted based on something as trivial as rep or vote count. Knowledge that I am a minority wouldn't make me condone such an act.

Comment: Perhaps I wrote question that was too controversial. Perhaps I should have written "How does reputation and votecount `flavor` your decision?" because I really feel that it does. Watch votes carefully on SO. You'll see that these sorts of things happen more often than not. It's a direct consequence of having reputation and votes so prominently displayed. If answers and questions were based on their merits alone, the "numbers" wouldn't be so prominent.

Comment: Interesting that at +3/-14 this is still nett rep +ve

Comment: @Rich... yes, that's the problem with rep not being based on the question's net vote score. Plus 14 user had to give up rep to express this.

Comment: @soft, flagging doesn't cost rep (some of those -1 may be flags)

Comment: It makes my heart warm and fuzzy to think that someone felt that the question had 'some' redeeming value. I still feel meta-voting is, if nothing else, an interesting discussion point. Perhaps I'm just stubborn.

Comment: @Downvoter: No, Rich's point is: +3 votes = +30 rep; -14 votes = -28 rep; result = net positive rep of 2 points even though negative votes greatly outnumber positive.

Answer (score 12):

When you hover over the voting arrows for questions and answers, here's what you see:

> This question is useful and clear
>
> This question is unclear or not useful
>
> This answer is useful
>
> This answer is not useful

These are the criteria you should be using to cast your votes.

SO is all about getting the best answer to a question with the help of the community.

If you're voting to engender competition or spur on controversy, you're **doing it wrong**.

If you're voting based on Rep like it's a popularity contest, you're **doing it wrong**.

If you're voting out of pity, you're **doing it wrong**.

In short, I think you're pretty much **doing it wrong**.

Comment: @tvanfosson: Okay, maybe SO isn't *all* about getting the best answer to a question. It's at least in some small part about unicorns and waffles too.

Comment: It used to be about ponies, but the ponies grew horns.

Comment: Great - <sigh> - we're back to talking about horny ponies.

Answer (score 2):

I don't vote nearly as much as maybe I should.  There's just so much that I see on SO that I don't know enough about to cast an informed vote on, so I don't.  If I point my browser *directly* at SO, I'm normally going to go moderator stuff, so I don't cast many votes.

A typical voting pattern for me goes like this, though:

- Have a problem I don't know how to solve.
- Google it.
- Find a link to SO (getting more frequent all the time).
- Read the question and the answers to see if it can help me.
- Upvote the answer(s) that helps me the most, and the question because it saved me some time.

Also, if I see a question that I think is good enough to spend time answering, I'll usually upvote it and a few of the other answers. (Only *usually* because I often forget.)

Those two scenarios together are probably how about 99% of my votes get cast.  I will *very rarely* go look for something to vote up if someone leaves a stellar edit that I think should be rewarded, but not much else plays into my decision to vote.

Comment: I upvote answers by people with googly-eyed unicorn gravatars. We googly-eyed unicorn types need to stick together.  Actually, I mostly just like to say "googly-eyed" and will pretty much upvote anyone who gives me the chance to say (or type) it.

Comment: Careful tv... Isn't that meta-voting? <tongue in cheek>